# How to fix size and position of background image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    var height2 = AppBar().preferredSize.height;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image(
              image: AssetImage("assets/oral_structure.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.fill
          ),
          Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:100, left: 100),
          child: Container(
              height: 60,
              width: 60,
              child: FlatButton(
                child: Text('ㅂ', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),

                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => B()),);
                },
              )
          ),
          ),
```

Above is part of my code. The app I'm making is where the appropriate button is placed on top of the background image. However, if you make the code above, the position of the button and the position of the image are different depending on the screen size of the smartphone. The same goes for fixing the height and width. How come there is no way?

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
        key: v.scaffoldKey,
        body: Stack(
            children: [
            getBackgroundLight(),
            ],
        ),
    );
} 

Widget getBackgroundLight() {
    return Stack(
        children: [
        Image.asset('assets/background.jpg', width: double.infinity),
        Transform.rotate(
            angle: -SizeConfig.calculateBlockVertical(180) *
              (math.pi / SizeConfig.calculateBlockVertical(180)),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.center,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                    Get.theme.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                    Get.theme.scaffoldBackgroundColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
    );
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.